# Как различаются функции (*Row) Scan() и (*Rows) Scan()?

Tags: sql, golang

1. `db.QueryRow("SELECT 'columnValue' FROM 'myTable' WHERE 'columnID' = ?", rowID).Scan(&prm)`
2. `db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM 'myTable' WHERE 'columnToken' = ?", myToken).Scan(&tokenText)`

В первом случае (выбираю значение из строки по идентификатору_строки) нормально возвращает найденное значение из ячейки - получается, что работает функция (*Row) Scan().
А во втором случае (определяю, есть ли строка с данным_значением) ругается: sql: expected 6 destination arguments in Scan, not 1 - получается работа функции (*Rows) Scan().
Как записать правильно во втором случае? И как эти две функции различаются в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueryRow()` абсолютно всегда возвращает только одну строку(тип `*Row`) из результата запроса.

Для запроса произвольного количества строк(тип *Rows) используется функция `Query`

А ошибка:

> sql: expected 6 destination arguments in Scan, not 1

Значит вовсе не то что вы написали... Она говорит о том, что запрос к базе вернул строку с 6-ю колонками, а типом переданной вами в `Scan()` переменной `&tokenText` является структура с одним полем вместо ожидаемых шести..

Comment: Я понял что это за ошибка. И что возвращается одна строка (в обоих примерах) я тоже знаю, мне и надо вернуть одну строку (только для разных целей в данных примерах).
Вопрос про то, что [при запросе к одной и той же таблице] в первом случае Scan() нормально принимает одно возвращенный столбец (в виде значения), а во втором случае на один возвращенный столбец ругается (хочет все столбцы таблицы).

Comment: А вопрос про вообще (не про конкретные примеры и ошибку): есть две разные функции - (*Row) Scan() и (*Rows) Scan(), с практически одинаковым синтаксисом, как их использовать правильно? Чтобы компилятор их различал.

Comment: > tokenText является структура с одним полем вместо ожидаемых шести
(Корректировка. Сразу неправильно понял.) Это понятно. Но в первом примере все тоже самое, но не ругается.

Comment: @Norik_A,  ну у вас попросту никак и никогда не получится вызвать функцию `(*Rows) Scan()`, для типа `*Row` - нету в Go такой возможности.. Повторюсь: `QueryRow()` всегда возвращает только `*Row` - вызывая `Scan()` вы всегда вызываете именно `(*Row) Scan()`,  а не какую-то другую функцию.

Comment: @Norik_A, у вас различается SQL-запрос переданный параметром в `QueryRow()` - в первом случае вы явно запрашиваете именно одну колонку текстового типа(поле "columnValue"), а во втором случае неявно запрашиваете 6(через использование '*') - поэтому во втором случае и возвращается вышеописанная ошибка, т.к. 6 полей из результата никак не впихнуть в структуру с одним полем..

Comment: > неявно запрашиваете 6(через использование '*')
Да, точно! С этим разобрались. Здесь надо в Scan() передавать все столбцы.

Comment: > никак и никогда не получится вызвать функцию (*Rows) Scan(), для типа *Row...
Да. Но можно вызвать [одноименную] функцию (*Rows) Scan() для типа *Rows. В этом как раз и вопрос: как увидеть/узнать/определить, что в данном случае тип *Row (а не *Rows)? Это следует лишь из контекста? Если Scan() использован с функцией, возвращающей только одну строку - значит это тип *Row; если с функцией, возвращающей много строк - это тип *Rows?